# Not able to add to material design elements to boilerplate app

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-template

I am trying to add material design elements to [quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) angular app

In app.module.ts added the following:

```
import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, MaterialModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

In app.component.ts added the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular App</h1><md-slide-toggle>Slide Toggle</md-slide-toggle>',
})
```

Here is the plunkr
[**http://plnkr.co/edit/gAIVxRTA0QZNu3uTC66k?p=preview**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gAIVxRTA0QZNu3uTC66k?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO** : http://plnkr.co/edit/IpeusijLdoTb6p27m7d7?p=preview

---

You are missing required things as mentioned below,

**1)** *you need to add **angular2-material** package first in order to use it.*

**`systemjs.config.js`**

```
'@angular/material':'npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js',  //<<<### added this
```

**2)** *angular2-material requires **hammer.js** support. So, you also need to include it in **index.html***

**`index.html`**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding the following to systemjs.config.js solved the problem

```
packages: {
  '@angular/material': {
    format: 'cjs',
    main: 'material.umd.js'
  }
}
```

or the following also solves:

```
'@angular/material':'npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js'
```

Comment: you would need it for sure. `angular2-material` uses `hammer.js` for its components for your kind information.